# Realtek Wifi Dongle - Centos7

Tags: wifi, usb

I am trying to get the a realtek USB wifi dongle working on my PC.

When I run lsusb - it is visible.

0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

System Version Information

LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
Release:    7.6.1810
Codename:   Core

Answer (score 1):

Googling on `0bda:0811` reveals that the WiFi chip in the dongle is Realtek RTL8812au.

Apparently [you may need to build the `8812au` driver from source code.](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au)

[Here seems to be Centos7-specific compilation instructions:](https://github.com/stevekay/centos7/blob/master/wifi.md)

```
$ yum install -y git gcc kernel-devel
[snip]
$ git clone git@github.com:gnab/rtl8812au.git
Cloning into 'rtl8812au'...
[snip]
$ cd rtl8812au
$ make
[snip]
  LD [M]  /home/steve/wifi/rtl8812au/8812au.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/steve/wifi/rtl8812au/8812au.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/steve/wifi/rtl8812au/8812au.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-514.6.2.el7.x86_64'
```

If this is successful, you can now try loading the module:

```
$ sudo insmod 8812au.ko
```

Apparently the WiFi adapter name may use the `en` prefix instead of the expected `wl`. If your system does not crash and e.g. `ip addr` command (or the NetworkManager desktop widget, if you use one) indicates that a new NIC is detected once you load the module, you can install it persistently with:

```
$ sudo cp 8812au.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
$ sudo depmod
```

You will need to recompile this driver each time you install a new kernel update.

Comment: Hi, Many thans for details. So now I can see thw wireless networks using iwconfig, but I am struggling to get it connected. I am following the link you suggested https://github.com/stevekay/centos7/blob/master/wifi.md but not connecting so far. Ill keep trying any advice in the meantime greatly appreciated

Comment: I get the following sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i enp0s29f7u2 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
rfkill: Cannot get wiphy information
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted

Comment: Apparently you might need a newer version of the `wireless-tools` package than is available in standard CentOS 7. You can get it with: `sudo yum -y install epel-release; sudo yum -y install wireless-tools`.

Comment: Hi
Ran both commands - no updates found "Package 1:wireless-tools-29-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do"